# When to use $t'=t\gamma$ when to use $t'=\gamma(t-vx/c^2)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames

I'm a bit confused imagine the following question:
X moves to Y ($T_0$ light years away) with speed $v$ and Y is stationary. Z observes X's trip from earth. How long X moves in its own reference frame and in Z's reference frame?

I am confused which formula to use $t'=\gamma t$ or $t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$ . I know that x refers to distance between reference frames but distance between Z and X constantly changes. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does X move to Z instead of Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you write down coordinates $(x,t)$ or $(x',t')$, you are listing the coordinates of a specific **event** in two distinct reference frames.

If those frames are related by a Lorentz transformation, then their origins coincide in the sense that the event whose coordinates in frame $S$ are $(0,0)$ also has coordinates $(0,0)$ in frame $S'$.  In this case, an event with coordinates $(x,t)$ in frame $S$ has coordinates $(x',t')$ in frame $S'$ where
$$x' = \gamma(x-vt)$$
$$t' = \gamma(t - vx/c^2)$$

To apply this to your question, we need to frame it in terms of events.  Let event $A$ refer to the departure of the ship from Earth, and event $B$ refer to the arrival of the ship at its destination.  Coordinate system $S$ is the inertial frame of an observer sitting still$^\dagger$ on Earth, and coordinate system $S'$ is the inertial frame of the spaceship moving with velocity $\mathbf v = v \hat x$ with respect to Earth.  For convenience, we may define event $A$ to be the origin of both reference frames, i.e. $(x_A,t_A) = (x'_A,t'_A) = (0,0)$.

In coordinate system $S$, the spatial coordinate of the ship's desination is $x_B = T_0 c$, and the arrival occurs at time $t_B = T_0 c / v$.  From this fact and the Lorentz transform equations, we can readily obtain the coordinates $(x'_B, t'_B)$ which correspond to the arrival of the ship at its destination in the ship's frame.   You will observe that $x'_B < x_B$, an effect which is usually called *length contraction*, and that $t_B>t'_B$, an effect which is usually called *time dilation*$^{\dagger\dagger}$.

---

> I am confused which formula to use $t'=\gamma t$ or $t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$ . I know that x refers to distance between reference frames but distance between Z and X constantly changes.

Unsurprisingly, you use the formula $t'= \gamma t$ if $x=0$. $x$ refers to the **coordinate** of the event in question in frame $S$, which is not the distance between frames.

---

$^\dagger$We will ignore the fact that astronomical bodies (Earth, the ship's destination, etc) are generally not stationary with respect to one another.

$^{\dagger\dagger}$The so-called *proper length* of an object (which in this case we might imagine to be a great celestial ruler whose ends lie at the position of the Earth and the ship's destination, respectively) is measured in the frame in which the object is a rest - in this case, that would be $S$. The so-called *proper time* between events is the time as measured by an observer to whom the events occur in the same place. Sweeping some important details under the rug, the lengths measured in other frames appear to be shorter then the proper length (hence length *contraction*) and times measured in other frames appear to be longer than the proper time (hence time *dilation*).

Comment: Can you show t' and t for X and Z reference frames if v=0.6c and T_0=4 light years as an example.

Comment: @HakanAkgün You should be able to plug whatever values you like into the expressions in my answer. If you can't, then that suggests you don't understand what I wrote, and I would be happy to clarify if you can identify the part that you find confusing.

Comment: I've understood but I just want to be sure whether I've understood correctly. For example for the case that I've mentioned.I've calculated the t(time measured by Z)=4LY/(0.6c)=6.66years and t'=(6.66years-(0.6c*4LY)/c^2)*gamma where gamma=1/sqrt(1-0.36). I'm able to do these calculations but I want to know that whether I'm doing correct or not.

Comment: @HakanAkgün That looks right to me. In the future, please take a look at this [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help make your questions and comments more readable.

Comment: Okay thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The Lorentz transformation equations allows you calculate the coordinates of an event in a new reference frame (RF) if you already know the coordinates in a first RF.

In the Lorentz transformation equation $x$ is not the distance between the RFs, it is the $x$-coordinate of the event in the "un-primed" RF.  $x'$ is the $x$-coordinate of same event in the "primed" RF.

To calculate the time duration $\Delta t = t_f - t_i$, the difference between the initial and final time, you actually need to transform two time coordinates: $t_i$ and $t_f$ $\rightarrow$ $t'_i$ and $t'_f$.  You can simplify matters by setting $t_i = 0$.  But if the two events happen at different spacial locations $x_i$ and $x_f$, as is the case for the start and end of the journey, you need to keep track of that.

Let's define event $i$ as "person X leaves" and assign it the coordinates $t_i = 0$ and $x_i = 0$ in Z's RF.  We can calculate $t'_i$ using the Lorentz transformation.
$$ t'_i = \gamma\left(t_i - \frac{v}{c^2}x_i\right) = 0 $$

Now we define event $f$ as "person X arrives at Y".  In Z's RF event $f$ has coordinates $t_f = \frac{\ell}{v}$ and $x_f = \ell$, where $\ell$ is the one light-year distance and $v$ is person X's speed.  There's a bunch of algebra needed to simplify down to the final expression, which I'll leave for you to work out.
$$ t'_f = \gamma\left(t_f - \frac{v}{c^2}x_f\right) = \frac{t_f}{\gamma}$$

Finally, the duration of the journey according to person X's clock is the difference between the two: $\Delta t' = \frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}$.

This is the same answer as if you used the standard time dilation equation $$\Delta t = \gamma\, \Delta \tau,$$
where $\Delta\tau = \Delta t'$ the proper time measured by the the moving clock.  The standard equation only works if both events occur at the same $x'$ location.  Person X would assign $x'_i = 0$ and $x'_f = 0$ since both events (X leaves and X arrives) happen where they are.  You could check this by calculating $x'_i$ and $x'_f$ using the appropriate Lorentz transformation too.

Answer (score 0):

Both $t$ and $x$ in the Lorentz transformation formula you mention refers to coordinate, not duration or distance (which are differences of two coordinates). In the case you ask about, you want to find duration of trip. This is difference of two times, and obeys the time dilation rule:

$$
\text{duration of trip according to moving clocks} = \frac{\text{duration according to stationary clocks}}{\gamma}.
$$

That's why the duration is shorter according to the moving clocks.

Answer (score 0):

Both formulae, applied correctly, will give the same result. One confusing point is that the primed and unprimed frames are different between the two equations you have written down. Let's make this clearer by rewriting the first equation as

$$\Delta\tau=\Delta t/\gamma.$$

This equation describes how much proper time $\Delta\tau$ elapses for an observer, moving at $v$ with respect to our coordinate system, in a coordinate time interval $\Delta t$. For your problem, if the traveler moves to distance $x$ (measured in the Earth frame), then they do so in Earth time $\Delta t=x/v$ or proper time $\Delta\tau=x/(\gamma v)$.

The second equation,
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right),$$
takes the coordinates $(t,x)$ of an event in the unprimed frame and yields its time coordinate $t^\prime$ in the primed frame, where the primed frame is moving at $v$ with respect to the unprimed frame. (The two frames share a coordinate origin.) For your problem, we can say the Earth frame is the unprimed frame and the traveler's frame is the primed frame. The origin of both coordinate systems is the traveler's departure. Then the traveler's arrival is at position $x$ and time $t=x/v$ in the Earth frame and hence time
$$t'
=\gamma\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)
=\gamma\left(\frac{x}{v}-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)
=\gamma\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)\frac{x}{v}
=\frac{x}{\gamma v}
$$
in the traveler's frame, just as in the calculation above. Here I used the definition of the Lorentz factor,
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}.$$